# What could cause this ProFTPD directory listing error?

Tags: cygwin, ftp

The error I get in Filezilla is "Cannot get directory listing". In Firefox it just keeps on loading and nothing happens. For both clients the same messages appear in proftpd.log.

```
Computer - error setting write fd TCP_NOPUSH: Protocol not available
Computer - error setting read fd TCP_NOPUSH: Protocol not available
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - FTP session opened.
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - PRIVS_USER: unable to seteuid(session.login_uid): Invalid argument
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - USER testing: Login successful.
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - error: /var/log is a world writeable directory
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - PRIVS_USER: unable to seteuid(session.login_uid): Invalid argument
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - PRIVS_SETUP: unable to seteuid(): Invalid argument
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - PRIVS_RELINQUISH: unable to seteuid(session.uid): Invalid argument
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - PRIVS_RELINQUISH: unable to seteuid(session.uid): Invalid argument
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - FTP no transfer timeout, disconnected
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - FTP session closed.
Computer - error setting write fd TCP_NOPUSH: Protocol not available
Computer - error setting read fd TCP_NOPUSH: Protocol not available
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - FTP session opened.
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - no such user 'ftp'
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - USER ftp: no such user found from 193.140.12.170 [193.140.12.170] to 192.168.10.138:21
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - FTP session closed.
Computer - error setting write fd TCP_NOPUSH: Protocol not available
Computer - error setting read fd TCP_NOPUSH: Protocol not available
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - FTP session opened.
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - PRIVS_USER: unable to seteuid(session.login_uid): Invalid argument
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - USER testing: Login successful.
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - error: /var/log is a world writeable directory
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - PRIVS_USER: unable to seteuid(session.login_uid): Invalid argument
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - PRIVS_SETUP: unable to seteuid(): Invalid argument
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - PRIVS_RELINQUISH: unable to seteuid(session.uid): Invalid argument
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - PRIVS_RELINQUISH: unable to seteuid(session.uid): Invalid argument
Computer (193.140.12.170[193.140.12.170]) - PRIVS_RELINQUISH: unable to seteuid(session.uid): Invalid argument
```

ProFTPD is installed via Cygwin, although they say this is not a Cygwin issue.

I have tried adding the following entries:

```
IdentLookups off
UseReverseDNS off
```

Unfortunately it still cannot successfully provide directory listing. Apache-server via cygwin can perfectly host the same directory.